# ASP.NET MVC - Extract parameter of an URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to extract the parameters of my URL, something like this.

*/Administration/Customer/Edit/1*

### **extract:** 1

*/Administration/Product/Edit/18?allowed=true*

### **extract:** 18?allowed=true

*/Administration/Product/Create?allowed=true*

### **extract:** ?allowed=true

Someone can help? Thanks!

Comment: In which context do you want to extract the parameters? from client side ?

Comment: I wanna extract in server-side

Comment: I would like to know how to do it in the client side. Specially for the first example (extract: 1)

Comment: You can check this example: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Extracting-Parameters-from-URL-in-NET-MVC

Answer (score 107, accepted):

**Update**

```
RouteData.Values["id"] + Request.Url.Query
```

Will match all your examples

---

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve.  MVC passes URL parameters for you through model binding.

```
public class CustomerController : Controller {

  public ActionResult Edit(int id) {

    int customerId = id //the id in the URL

    return View();
  }

}


public class ProductController : Controller {

  public ActionResult Edit(int id, bool allowed) { 

    int productId = id; // the id in the URL
    bool isAllowed = allowed  // the ?allowed=true in the URL

    return View();
  }

}
```

Adding a route mapping to your global.asax.cs file before the default will handle the /administration/ part.  Or you might want to look into MVC Areas.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Admin", // Route name
  "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
```

If it's the raw URL data you are after then you can use one of the various URL and Request properties available in your controller action

```
string url = Request.RawUrl;
string query= Request.Url.Query;
string isAllowed= Request.QueryString["allowed"];
```

It sounds like `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` could be what you want.

If you want access to the raw posted data you can use

```
string isAllowed = Request.Params["allowed"];
string id = RouteData.Values["id"];
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public ActionResult Index(int id,string value)
```

This function get values form URL 
After that you can use below function

**`Request.RawUrl`** - Return complete URL of Current page

**`RouteData.Values`** - Return Collection of Values of URL

**`Request.Params`** - Return Name Value Collections

Comment: Use  Request.QueryString["id"]

Answer (score 1):

You can get these parameter list in ControllerContext.RoutValues object as key-value pair.

You can store it in some variable and you make use of that variable in your logic.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this method:

```
    private string GetUrlParameter(HttpRequestBase request, string parName)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        var urlParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.Url.Query);
        if (urlParameters.AllKeys.Contains(parName))
        {
            result = urlParameters.Get(parName);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And I call it like this:

```
string fooBar = GetUrlParameter(Request, "FooBar");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fooBar))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the values of your parameters, you can use `RouteData`.

More context would be nice. Why do you need to "extract" them in the first place? You should have an Action like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, bool allowed) {}
```

Comment: Yes. I do Url.Action("Edit", "Product", new { id = 10, allowed = true }) and just wanna get the parameters. I'll send it to the client-side.

Comment: I'll get it on server-side and send the parameters to client-side.

Answer (score -5):

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET but I guess you could use a **split** function to split it in an array using the / as delimiter, then **grab the last element in the array** (usually the array length -1) to get the extract you want.

Ok this does not seem to work for all the examples.

What about a regex?

```
.*(/|[a-zA-Z]+\?)(.*)
```

then get that last subexpression `(.*)`, I believe it's `$+` in .Net, I'm not sure

Comment: This is not necessary in .NET and MVC, the `RouteData` and `Request.Url` objects contain the data required already split into parts for you.