# ASP.NET MVC - Get parameter value from URL in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, url-routing

How do I get parameter value from the URL in the client side, view?

URL:

```
localhost:18652/category/1
```

MapRoute:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "ResultsByCategory",
     url: "category/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ResultsByCategory"}
 );
```

How do I get ID?

Comment: in controller Home create method ResultsByCategory that takes id as parameter

Comment: I have this method. I want to get ID value in my view.

Comment: there are several options, you can pass it in the model (pass the model when you return the view in ResultsByCategory) or use ViewBag, ViewData or TempData, depending on what you want to do

Comment: I don't want to pass this value from controller to view. I need to get it directly from url, request etc., but in my view.

Comment: I think there is no query string in this url, am i wrong?

Comment: Sorry, try Request.Url.ToString(). I believe QueryString only contains parameters. If you split by '/' and get the Last(), this would make the trick.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003953/asp-net-mvc-extract-parameter-of-an-url

Comment: I think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003953/asp-net-mvc-extract-parameter-of-an-url

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested this url:

```
http://localhost:1865/category/Index/1
```

In view I have this:

[image: getID]

You can get id by this code in example view:

```
@{
    var id = Request.Url.Segments[3];
}
```

In general case, You can use this code:

```
@{
    var id = Request.Url.Segments.Last();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Didn't understand the point of directly getting from URL, Request as your view is always going to get loaded from your controller.

So as derloopkat suggested

In your Home Controller

```
Public ActionResult ResultsByCategory (int id)
{
  ViewBag.id = id;
  return View();
}
```

In your view you can use it by calling

```
@ViewBag.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works better for your code

```
string id = Request.Path.Value.Split('/').LastOrDefault();
```